# The SoundCloud WordPress plugin generates mixed-content errors when viewing pages over HTTPS

Tags: soundcloud

Hello SoundCloud Team :)

When embedding SoundCloud items into WordPress via the [SoundCloud Shortcode plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/soundcloud-shortcode/), the iframe's `src` is [set to](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/soundcloud-shortcode/trunk/soundcloud-shortcode.php#L162) `w.soundcloud.com/player?url=...`.  Apparently, the correct URL is `w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=...` (with a trailing slash).

When the page is served over HTTPS, the iframe's non-trailing-slashed `src`'s scheme is correctly set to `https`.  However, the non-traling-slashed https URL is redirected to a trailing-slashed *http* URL, which causes a mixed-content error and prevents the embed from loading.

```
$ curl -IL 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/142702630&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&visual=true'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/142702630&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&visual=true
...

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/142702630&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&visual=true
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

One (or both) of the following would solve the issue.

1. Change the redirect to go to an https URL.
2. Update the plugin to point to the correct URL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like a bug report.

Comment: Yes it is not really a question.

Comment: Yeah - I wasn't sure what to do.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/support suggests that their team watches this tag.  I couldn't find anything specifically for bug reports.

Comment: But doesn't SoundCloud have a **[specific embed method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792843/player-html5-soundcloud/33793398#33793398)** for WordPress posts? Maybe they prefer that method is used instead of i-frames since that doesn't complain about mixed-content warnings?

Comment: Just found if you drop the "**s**" in the wordpress embed link then it works but dunno if that has future issues. example: **[http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/188034822](http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/188034822)** (before was : https ://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/188034822)

Answer (score 1):

I dug around a bit and had found effectively the same answer on:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-does-not-work-with-website-ssl

I can say that if you are having an issue with SoundCloud on WordPress over SSL, add the '/' character as recommended and the *problem simply goes away*. That is, alter the URL in the `soundcloud_iframe_widget()` function to add '/' prior to the trailing '?' in

```
 // Build URL
  $url = 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?' . http_build_query($options['params']);
```

in the file

```
$WORDPRESS_HOME/wp-content/plugins/soundcloud-shortcode/soundcloud-shortcode.php
```

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

> add the '/' character as recommended and the problem simply goes away. That is, alter the URL in the soundcloud_iframe_widget() function to add '/' prior to the trailing '?

Thanks! that worked perfectly with chrome and safari, but I still have the issue with firefox. But doing that did the trick :

```
$url = 'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/' . '?' . http_build_query($options['params']);
```