# Player html5 soundcloud

Tags: html, flash, soundcloud

I would like to change flash player SoundCloud to HTML5 player to my site in WordPress. The audios are add in pages.

I'm having problems because i cant find a code no user, just a player that work.

The flash code:

```
<object height="100%" width="100%"> 
<param name="movie" 
value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=<?=print_field($data,'sound_link') ?>&auto_play=false&player_type=artwork&color=000000"></param>
                                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                                    <embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="100%" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=<?=print_field($data,'sound_link') ?>&auto_play=false&player_type=artwork&color=000000" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed>
                                </object>
```

Comment: If my answer helps then please "upvote" it or even mark as "correct. Thanks. Otherwise explain what is wrong... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try code like this?

Simply create a new Wordpress post, give a title, then in main text area just insert the shown code below into it as if it was usual article text: (click "Save draft" and then try "Preview") :

```
[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/34019569" params="color=000000" width="100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]
```

note: You must use `http://` not the SSL version of `https://`.

**EDIT :**

First make sure you **install** the **[SoundCloud Short Code](http://blog.vcone.co.uk/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=search&type=term&s=SoundCloud%2BShortCode)** plugin (*made by SoundClound Inc*) :

For using SoundCloud URL as link, you can now try:

```
[soundcloud url="https://soundcloud.com/soulmovementrecords/dj-fleg-new-horns" params="auto_play=false&amp;show_comments=false" width="100%" height="150" /]
```

Here is a link to an example: **[SoundCloud Player test](http://blog.vcone.co.uk/2015/11/27/soundcloud-player-test/)** (using a page URL not user or track ID)

I assume using your code, you can try something like:

```
[soundcloud url="sound_link" params="auto_play=false&amp;show_comments=false" width="100%" height="150" /]
```

Comment: This could help, but how is `[soundcloud]` handled? You must have WP shortcode handler for that otherwise, it won't do anything.

Comment: @AdamAzad I think it works because SoundCloud have a WordPress approved embed **widget** so the WP system knows what `[soundcloud]` means within a WP blog post. See **[this example post](https://vcone.wordpress.com/2015/11/19/soundcloud-test-embed/)** using same code as above (only with different track number + bigger height)

Comment: HI there! Tks to answer. The link [soundcloud] works in posts and pages but the problems its the player no url defined. I'm trying to change sfw player to htlm5 but dont working!

Comment: I think in your code the `sound_link` is just a link to the SoundCloud page right? Where is information for `sound_link` coming from? Things have changed and these days you have to use `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/` with Track ID number. Check each song's page and click the `Share` button and choose `Embed` option for correct Track ID to use in WordPress

Comment: Hi! I have a wordpress portfolio that i can add audios and videos. In my admin, i can create a page withe audio, title, client and just put the link of soundcloud and had worked. I cant embed one by one audio with the embed WP code from soundcloud page, i need to change or fix the player and the player, cant have user. Regards

Comment: Can you try my edit code? If that doesn't work then please show code of how you make a post (not just the swf flash code). How can I recreate your problem in my wordpress? show the full code of a post example.

Comment: <div class="audioPlugin">

<?php if(print_field($data,"sound_link")){ ?>
[soundcloud url="sound_link" params="auto_play=false&amp;show_comments=false" width="100%" height="150" /]

Comment: Are you using a plugin called **SoundCloud Is Gold**? I was wondering why PHP etc is involved. Anyway this problem, only that author can fix it. I think Soundcloud really changed something on their servers. They already added "playing limits" so what else they've changed?. Anyway your question was how to use HTML5 player from Soundcloud and that's what I was showing you. Until fixed your only option is to use Soundcloud Short Code tool. You can use page URL there. If you need multiple tracks in one player then eithr create a new or share an exisiting playlist as embed link.